# Android get top activity its provide the own app info but not others

Tags: android

I have a service in which I want to get the current activity here is my code

```
ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
        ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
        String activityOnTop = ar.topActivity.getPackageName();

        Toast.makeText(this,activityOnTop+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

It works when I open my own app but it does not work when other app open it does not provides the packages. Thanks

Comment: If your app is not on the foreground, your app has no current activity. The other app does though

Comment: its working when i open my own app but not work when other app open

Comment: This is exactly what @TimCastelijns wrote.

Comment: Will you please explain some more